# getting the details to show above an annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mapkit

ok so I have my annotations showing up fine but I can't figure out how to get the little dialogue box thing to appear above it. When I create an annotation, I do this:

```
Annotation *annot = [[Annotation alloc] init];
annot.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
annot.title = @"Location";
annot.subtitle = @"The address";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annot];
```

Again, this works find but it doesn't show the little dialogue box.

I understand that I has something to do with a delegate. I downloaded apple's MapCallouts example code and couldn't figure out how they contacted the delegate to the annotations.

here is my annotations class

Annotation.H

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c 
                  title:(NSString *) t
               subtitle:(NSString *) st;

-(void) moveAnnotation: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) newCoordinate;

-(NSString *)subtitle;
-(NSString *)title;



@end
```

Annotation.m

```
#import "Annotation.h"

@implementation Annotation

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize subtitle = _subtitle;



-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t subtitle:(NSString *)st
{
    coordinate = c;
    self.title = t;
    self.subtitle = st;
    return self;
}

-(void)moveAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    coordinate = newCoordinate;
}

-(NSString *)subtitle {
    return subtitle;
}
-(NSString *)title{
    return title;
}
@end
```

Here is the delagate I set up:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{  
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"customAnn";

    MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = [aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (customAnnotationView == nil)
    {
        customAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        UIImage *pinImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-green.png"];
        [customAnnotationView setImage:pinImage];
        customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        customAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }

    customAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return customAnnotationView; 
}

return nil; 
}
```

If you need any more information from me, let me know and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the following MKMapViewDelegate method on your MKMapView's delegate:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

Make sure you return an [MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with `canShowCallout` enabled.

Comment: how do I set up a delegate for my map view?

Comment: Like this, right?:@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

Comment: yeah. make sure to actually set the delegate property of the mapView though (mapView.delegate = self;)

Comment: ok I did that but now I can't see my pins. I can tell everything else is working but the pins are not dropping =/

Comment: Ok I got my delegate to work. My pins are now appearing and I even got them to animate the drop down... but still not pop up thing

Comment: got it! my annotation class was confusing two different things

Comment: changed to this: -(NSString *)subtitle {
        return _subtitle;
    }
    -(NSString *)title{
        return _title;
    }